# How can we get data from SQL Server database to a textbox in c# with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, sql-server-2014

I want to create an account form for user that logged in order to edit his/her information, but I do not know how to get the record that the information of that user is saved in the database. It's for a library system. I'm using Entity Framework 6.

```
private void Account_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // LibraryModel.LibraryEntities1 context = new LibraryModel.LibraryEntities1();

    string naw;
    name.Text = StaticClass.Username;
    pass.Text = StaticClass.pass;

    naw = name.Text;

    using (var context = new LibraryModel.LibraryEntities1())
    {
        var posts = context.tbl_user
                           .Where(p => p.Name == naw)
                           .Select(p => new Account()
                               {
                                   na = p.UserName,
                               });

        email.Text = posts.ToString();
        // Do Something
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some code. Show us what you have tried.

Comment: I add codes but do not work

Comment: Where is the definition for you Context Sets

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon id's you have assigned to text boxes and values from database you can edit my answer here am pasting code for you so edit it.

```
(var context = new BloggingContext()) { 
YoutextboxID.text = context.Personnels
.Where(p => p.Id == 1234567)
.Select(p => p.Name).FirstOrDefault(); }
```

Comment: I have edited my answer you can use that or edit you question and show your code so we can answer.